# formatting url characters

Tags: java, php, url, url-rewriting

WHat will be the best practice to replace Unicode character in URL.
For example if I have a multilingual website and support East European languages

How should I format the URL that it always contains valid characters?

Comment: The English word you are looking for is "form" not "formate".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want todo is called slugify.

```
$slugified_url_part = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $url_part);
```

The above code will turn non ascii chars to it's closest ascii char.
You should also trim whitespace and replace inner whitespace with a dash or underscore.
Making all chars lowercase is also common.

Slugify is handy for remembering URLS and SEO.
You could ofcourse use percent encoding but that can look ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). Most languages have a helper function already built in.

> Percent-encoding, also known as URL encoding, is a mechanism for encoding information in a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) under certain circumstances. Although it is known as URL encoding it is, in fact, used more generally within the main Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) set, which includes both Uniform Resource Locator (URL) and Uniform Resource Name (URN). As such it is also used in the preparation of data of the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" media type, as is often used in email messages and the submission of HTML form data in HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

when using php you can use [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to build your urls

Answer (score 0):

The tags on this are a bit confusing, containing both PHP and Java.

For the Java side.

Use URLEncoder.encode("Your String Here", "UTF-8");